# What is the best way to implement mvc using backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, architecture

I'm working on hybrid mobile application which has its base on backbone. I'm newbie to backbone. It is taking enormous time to learn the structuring itself. The logic is to present information from service to the user and post the information to the server. The information gathering spans across multiple pages. and the presentation of information also span across multiple page. What is the best structure to go with this? I'm really worried how model and collection can be used in my requirement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check out aura - https://github.com/aurajs/aura - thats my personal preference

Comment: Thanks imrane.. But i prefer not to include another framework or library.. I'm expecting the construct to utilize the collection and model of backbone in efficient way..

Comment: honestly, you are going to need some framework on top of backbone like marionette, or aura for a multi-page app. Backbone doesn't do things like cleaning up zombie views, sharing collections and models, providing you a framework to organize your code and coordinating views to name a few. Trust me when I say you should look into those frameworks and checkout yeoman as well. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks imrane.. But my app is almost set to start work and crossed the stage of getting authorization of another framework. Still your information is really helpful.. I'm sure to take help of these framework in my next project.. Yet I'm struck to find a better way for my current project.. Based on your comments i can understand it is hard to get it done.. But i'm looking for doing whatever is possible with backbone max utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there is not enough information in your question to truly answer your problem.

But I can still give you some information.

Backbone is a MV* framework, it's two most important class being Model and View. The models works the usual way, and interact with the database. The views are far closer to the role of a Controller in usual MVC framworks, and take the information from the model to put it on the screen.

> The information gathering spans across multiple pages. and the presentation of information also span across multiple page. What is the best structure to go with this?

Backbone works best with single page applications, so you should try to keep your whole application on a single page (that doesn't mean the end router sees a single page, as the java script can re-render the page when needed).

You can share the information among views like that:

```
var model = Model();
var view1 = view1({model:model});
var view2 = view2({model:model});
```

All the views will be able to access to the same model with the same data.

Further reading:

beginner:[Backbone Tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/)

intermediate to expert : [Osmani's awesome book](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/)